# C#7: How to use tuples in generic methods (LINQ select example)

Tags: linq, generics, c#-7.0

I have some heavily repeating code, which has always the same structure, just using different columns in a database for accessing it  and doing similar stuff

A typical query looks like:

```
var portfolioIds = context.PortSelMotorSeries
                    .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.InstallationAltitudeMax })
                    .ToList();
```

Now I want to use a generic function for dependency inversion and to pass the selector function as a delegate to the query:

```
private void ForEachIterate<T1>(Func<MotorSeriesDb, T1> selectorFunc): where T1 : (int Id, double Value)
{
  ...
  var portfolioIds = context.PortSelMotorSeries
                        .Select(selectorFunct)
                        .ToList();
  ...
}
```

So that I can call the query with my own selector:

```
ForEachIterate(x => new { Id = x.Id, Value = x.InstallationAltitudeMax });
ForEachIterate(x => new { Id = x.Id, Value = x.TemperatureMax });
```

Specifying the constraint with "where T1 : (int Id, double Value)" leads to a compiler error  CS0701.

Leaving it away leads to other compiler errors.

**Is there any way to use tuples in generic functions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing you're confusing tuples (the `(int Id, double Value)` thing) with anonymous classes (the `new { Id = x.Id, Value = x.TemperatureMax }`). They aren't even related, so your code would never work as is.

For another, if all you want is to force the user to output a tuple of some specific type, you can do something like this:

```
private void ForEachIterate(Func<MotorSeriesDb, (int, double)> selectorFunc)
{
  ...
  var portfolioIds = context.PortSelMotorSeries
                        .Select(selectorFunct)
                        .ToList();
  ...
}

// call like:
ForEachIterate(x => (x.Id, x.InstallationAltitudeMax));
```

Note that there's nothing generic about your function at all. Which leads me to my third point: you're missing the entire point of Linq. You talk about inversion of control, but you're the one who's inverting it in the wrong direction to begin with.

You already have a construct that allows arbitrary selection: `context.PortSelMotorSeries`. Simply use Linq to select what you want out of it in the call site and you're done.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the C#7 syntax.
Thanks for the solution, it works.

Concerning the inversion of control, I think you are the one who misses the point. The world is a little more complex than the example here - repeating 90% similar queries on multiple tables is not really a good style.
Especially if it can be avoided with a one-liner function call and a generic implementation.

Comment: You are free to code as you wish, but making wide spanning statements like "is not really a good style" is just plain wrong. Everyone, including Microsoft themselves, use EF (core) in the same way: open a context and query. What you're doing here goes against everything `IQueryable` stands for.

Answer (score 1):

If you try this it could works:

```
private static void ForEachIterate<T1>(Func<MotorSeriesDb, T1> selectorFunc) where T1 : Tuple<int, double>
{
    var portfolioIds = context.PortSelMotorSeries
                .Select(selectorFunct)
                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution works, provided you use the tuple in the call: ForEachIterate(x => new Tuple<int, double>(x.Id, x.AmbientTemperatureMax);
The question stays: Is it possible with ValueTuple?